# AdWhirl and Admob

Tags: objective-c, iphone, admob, adwhirl

I have downloaded the latest AdWhirl and AdMob SDK. Read and done with the instructions in the AdWhirlSDKInstructionsforiPhone.pdf

I have the following errors:
1. AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count
2. Unable to fill ad request.  This is a common situation.
3. `<AdMob> Must implement required method -currentViewControllerForAd:(AdMobView *)adView in your delegate.

   <AdMob> The AdMob SDK requires a valid view controller to be returned from currentViewController (AdMobDelegateProtocol).  Cancelling ad request.`

What can be the problem? Please help me.

Comment: I can't speak much to the AdWhirl portion of the integration, but as far as AdMob is concerned... have you implemented the 'currentViewControllerForAd' method as required?

Comment: AdWhirl implemented the specified method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain a copy of the AdMob AdViewController as Admob no longer does this itself.

In your viewcontroller.h add something like

```
IBOutlet AdViewController *localAdViewController;
```

inside the @interface section, and add

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AdViewController *localAdViewController;
```

afterwards.

Then add a link in IB from File's owner to your localAdViewController in AdViewController.

Should work fine then on.